# Javascript module from “http://website.com/assets/js/Main.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)

Tags: javascript, module

everything is working fine on my xampp server, but it doesn't on my internet website and I'm getting this console output:

```
Loading module from “http://... Main.js” was blocked because of a
disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)
```

being main.js the first import in module.js

```
import { Main } from './folder/Main.js';
```

in index.html, this is how I import the main module:

```
<script type="module" src="assets/js/module.js"></script>
```

So, the all app is not starting, of course. I really have no idea why...
Thanks in advance

---

Solved: a very bizzarre filename case problem. Somewhere, *another* .js was importing 'main.js' instead of 'Main.js' and this was tolerated by my xampp server...

Comment: is the file served is javascript file. Try to open the url in the new tab and see if the right file is serverd.

Comment: Looks like your server is sending text/html as content type when it expects it to be application/javascript

Comment: Panther : yes, every .js is correctly served

Comment: Changing src="assets/js/module.js" to src="/assets/js/module.js" (with / in front) might help as well. If the path is not correct, you get a MIME mismatch as well.

Comment: @ bdbdbd: already tried... not working :(

Comment: @stv did you ever resolve this? If so, how?

Comment: @AlexMorrison something changed after a Firefox upgrade, I guess, because after a while everything was working propwerly. This weird behavior was only on localhost. Online, no problem.